# ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } U=0: not found

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

Since trying to update my Android application from Eclipse over to Android Studio (converting to a gradle project) I've been running into issues. I think I've smoothed over most of them, but I am unable to get notifications from GCM (which is an important part of the application).

Here is the message I from the Android phone getting the GCM message (these messages are posted from a server multi casting to multiple android devices):

```
    --------- beginning of main
2018-10-26 15:46:36.222 2921-2921/com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app V/GCMBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
2018-10-26 15:46:36.222 2921-2921/com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app V/GCMBroadcastReceiver: GCM IntentService class: com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.GCMIntentService
2018-10-26 15:46:36.225 2921-2921/com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app V/GCMBaseIntentService: Acquiring wakelock
2018-10-26 15:46:36.226 1686-3213/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app cmp=com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app/com.activate.gcm.GCMIntentService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
...
<permission
        android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.permission.RECEIVE" />
...
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ddv_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/PulseAppTheme" 
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:name=".GlobalVariables" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
...
```

I have also tried changing the `<service android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.GCMIntentService"` to `<service android:name=".GCMIntentService"` with the same results.

Basically what I can tell is that the Android device is getting the GCM message. And it knows that the GXM IntentService is my custom com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.GCMIntentService, but it's not doing anything with it... And it's not really throwing any error. The message i see in the logcat just looks like a warning if anything.

I've made sure my GCMIntentService is in the main package of the application. And that I have all the correct permissions so I'm not sure what I'm missing or why I can't get this to work.

I did have to change how my GCM registers when I updated my application and it's possible I still have this incorrect. But the following code is not throwing any errors and when I send out the GCM message from the server all of my Android devices get the message from above (making it look like they are registered correctly and getting something from Google).

GCM registration code:

```
if (gcm == null) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(RegisterActivity.this);
}
regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
Log.d(TAG, "########################################");
Log.d(TAG, "Current Device's Registration ID is: " + regId);
SharedPreferences prefs = RegisterActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("com.google.android.gcm", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("regId", regId);
editor.apply();
Log.d(TAG, "prefs.getString(\"regId\", \"\"): " + prefs.getString("regId", ""));
Log.d(TAG, "GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId: " + GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(RegisterActivity.this));
ServerUtilities.registerToGCMServer(RegisterActivity.this, regId);
```

ServerUtilities code:

```
static boolean registerToGCMServer(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device on GCM Server (regId = " + regId + ")");
    String baseUrl = getHost(context) + context.getString(R.string.GCM_PATH) + context.getString(R.string.GCM_REGISTER_PATH);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
    // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register it in the
    // demo server. As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
    // times.
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
        try {
            displayMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));
            post(baseUrl, params);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
            // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
            // (like HTTP error code 503).
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i, e);
            if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                Thread.sleep(backoff);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return false;
            }
            // increase backoff exponentially
            backoff *= 2;
        }
    }
    String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error, MAX_ATTEMPTS);
    CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
    return false;
}
```

Oh right final piece of info. Here is what I am expecting for my application to do: in my `GCMIntentService.java` I'm expecting the overwritten `onMessage()` function to be called which displays an alert based on the GCM message received.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
...
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String alertText = intent.getExtras().getString("text");
        String ackID = intent.getExtras().getString("id");
        String detailID = intent.getExtras().getString("detail_id");

        // Sets the class to be called when the notification is selected
        intent.setClass(context, AlertFragmentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("alert", (Parcelable) (new Alert(ackID, detailID, alertText)));

        // I think this only goes through if the app is already running?
        displayAlert(context, intent);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, intent);
    }
}
```

I know I'll eventually have to update to FCM, but this should still be working in the mean time (till April 2019 when GCM gets completely removed).

Comment: The thing is, even though GCM is still not completely removed, its officially been deprecated already. So many updates have been released since the initial, that at this point (IMHO) GCM's behavior is no longer reliable. The best suggestion would still be to migrate to FCM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I updated my registration from `GMCRegistrar.register()` to `GoogleCloudMessaging.register()` I had to update my broadcast receiver to a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

This [link](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/) gave me the code I needed to grab the updated GCM messages.

Full steps I took:

1. Created new Custom `WakefulBoradcastReciever` to get new GCM messages.

CGCMBroadcastReciever.java

```
package com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class CGCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "CGCMBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                CGCMIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

2. Created new `IntentService` to handle the new Intent created from receiving the GCM message.

CGCMIntentService.java

```
package com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.alerts.Alert;
import com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.alerts.AlertFragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import static com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app.CommonUtilities.displayAlert;

public class CGCMIntentService  extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "CGCMIntentService";

    private static final String DDV_GROUP_KEY = "ddv_group_key";

    // This "notifcationStyle" will hold all of the notifications that come in
    // It will only be cleared when a user goes to the Alert page
    public static NotificationCompat.InboxStyle notificationStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    public CGCMIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String alertText = intent.getExtras().getString("text");
        String ackID = intent.getExtras().getString("id");
        String detailID = intent.getExtras().getString("detail_id");

        // Sets the class to be called when the notification is selected
        intent.setClass(CGCMIntentService.this, AlertFragmentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("alert", (Parcelable) (new Alert(ackID, detailID, alertText)));

        // I think this only goes through if the app is already running?
        displayAlert(CGCMIntentService.this, intent);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(CGCMIntentService.this, intent);

        CGCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void generateNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String message = "Alert from " + intent.getStringExtra("text");
        //String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_example;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // build notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("DDV Alert")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setWhen(when)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setGroup(DDV_GROUP_KEY)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setStyle(notificationStyle.addLine(message))
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0,
                        0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0,
                        0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0 })
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app/raw/" + R.raw.annoying_alarm93))
                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 1000)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        //Set notification sound to max
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);

        //If user is not on a call send the notification
        //Else wait for the call to end to send the notification
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(telephony.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // start notification
            notificationManager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());
        } else {
            // create a handler to listen for the call to end
            Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
            GCMIntentService activity = new GCMIntentService();
            handler.post(activity.new TelephonyRunnable(context, telephony, notificationManager, nBuilder.build()));
        }
    }
}
```

3. Update AndroidManifest.xml to use the new custom services.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".CGCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.ddv.android.gcm.support.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
      Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
      handle received messages.

      By default, it must be named .CGCMIntentService, unless the
      application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.

    -->
    <service android:name=".CGCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```